# WP CLI theme install. Install a private repo?

Tags: scripts, wp-cli

I have a bash script that installs and activates a theme like this:

wp theme install https://bitbucket.org/organization/theme/get/master.zip --activate

The problem is that it only works with public repositories, rather than private ones. If I make the repository private I get this error:

```
Unpacking the package...
Warning: The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
```

Is there a way I can install private repositories that I have ssh keys and passwords for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually figured out a way to do this. First you use wget like this:

```
wget --user username --ask-password -O path/to/output.zip https://bitbucket.org/path/to/file.zip
```

the -O flag specifies output and output.zip is where you want it to download to.

Then you can run:

```
wp theme install path/to/output.zip --activate
```

Happy days

Answer (score 1):

I like to run my grab from a php script.  I happen to do git clone instead of wget, but the same principals will still apply.  Try something like this:

```
git clone "https://bitBucketUsername:bitBucketPassword@bitbucket.org/organization/theme/get/master.git"
```

In practice, you'll need to escape your username and password, like so.

```
$bitBucketUsername = "bob.smith@gmail.com";
$bitBucketPassword = 'ILikeTurtles';
$bitBucketCredentials = urlencode($bitBucketUsername).':'.urlencode($bitBucketPassword).'@';
$cmd = "git clone \"https://{$bitBucketCredentials}bitbucket.org/organization/theme/get/master.git\"";

exec($cmd, $output, $return);
if ($return != 0) {
    if (is_array($output)) {
            $output = var_export($output, true);
    }
    print "Yikes, got ($return).  output: $output";
} else {
    // seems to have worked
    // maybe activate the plugin?
}
```

For a more secure solution when using git, search on 'helper credentials'